# Ajax DataTable Timeout

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables

I have a lot of data in the datatable and it turns out that the response time is over, I'm using paging, but the problem is that I need to query all the data to make the total value. I tried to make a timeout, but that does not work, it keeps bugging me anyway.

```
params.Datatable = params.ElementTable.DataTable({
    "ordering": false,
    "iDisplayLength": 5,
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "timeout": 300000,
    "paging": params.Pagination == undefined ? true : params.Pagination,
    "ajax": {
        url: params.ElementTable.attr("data-url"),
        dataType: "json",
        data: params.Data,
        type: "POST",

        dataSrc: function (result) {

            if (result.total)
                for (var prop in result.total)
                    params.ElementTable.find("tfoot tr th[data-data='" + prop + "']").html(result.total[prop]);

            if (params.Callback)
                params.Callback(result);

            return result.data;

        }

    }
```

And also tried to do:

```
params.Datatable = params.ElementTable.DataTable({
    "ordering": false,
    "iDisplayLength": 5,
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "paging": params.Pagination == undefined ? true : params.Pagination,
    "ajax": {
        url: params.ElementTable.attr("data-url"),
        dataType: "json",
        data: params.Data,
        type: "POST",
        timeout: 300000,

        dataSrc: function (result) {

            if (result.total)
                for (var prop in result.total)
                    params.ElementTable.find("tfoot tr th[data-data='" + prop + "']").html(result.total[prop]);

            if (params.Callback)
                params.Callback(result);

            return result.data;

        }

    }
});
```

Comment: can you make try with two queries? One is to get the count and another for the data? This might help you from getting timeout error.

Answer (score 0):

Setting Timeout remains the solution to this.
I had this issue and solved it increasing my timeout from the 50s to 100s.. (large data).
So you have to increase the timeout on the server-side.
You didn't mention what backend you are using.